# bitbake IMAGE_INSTALL with virtual packages / multiple providers

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded, yocto-recipe

In my layers I have multiple machines (different architectures) and I have multiple applications for the same purpose. Every architecture has a preferred (default) application which goes into IMAGE_INSTALL but those applications can be removed later and replaced with a different application (so they are conflicting).
My applicaitons:

- X.bb
- X-a.bb (variant 1)
- X-a-b.bb (variant 2)
- Y-c.bb (variant 1)
- Y-d.bb (variant 2)
- Z.bb

These are all conflicting (only one should be installed at a time).

My machines:

- MACH1
- MACH2

My intention (for example):

MACH1: installs X-a package by default but is compatible with X-a-b

MACH2: install Y-c package by default but is compatible with Y-d and Z

I tried to add RPROVIDES_${PN} += "virtual/X" to my X.bb X-a.bb and X-a-b.bb file and PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/X = "X-a" to my MACH1.conf file.
I have a problem when I want to build the appropriate application I just type in

```
bitbake virtual/X
```

and I get the following error

> dpkg-deb: error: parsing file ... 'Provides' field, invalid package
> name 'virtual/X': character '/' not allowed

also IMAGE_INSTALL doesn't work with virtual packages only "real" names are allowed here.

> ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'X'....

So in the end I'm stuck 2x because I can't build my .deb packages neither my image. What would be a decent solution?

p.s.:
I still don't get why PROVIDES = "virtual/X" doesn't work with IMAGE_INSTALL also find it strange PREFERRED_PROVIDER aligns with RPROVIDES but not PROVIDES variable.
And for some reasons it seems like this method is not meant for installable packages but for kernels or whatsoever...

Can you please help me?

Comment: Note that `virtual` keyword has no special meaning when it comes to runtime deps (RPROVIDES/RDEPENDS), it is only supported with DEPENDS/PROVIDES. Some discussion can be found here: https://www.mail-archive.com/openembedded-core@lists.openembedded.org/msg152558.html

Comment: can you share .bb file